Calculate variables within family in a long format dataset
I have a data set like this one:
df <- data.frame(FAMID = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
                 IID =   c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","B"),
                 Value = c(3,6,3,5,6,7,0,4,4))
#   FAMID IID Value
# 1     1   A     3
# 2     1   B     6
# 3     2   A     3
# 4     2   B     5
# 5     3   A     6
# 6     4   B     7
# 7     5   A     0
# 8     5   B     4
# 9     6   B     4

And I need to calculate some variables (the difference score for the variable Value and the mean, for each pair of members). So, I would need an output like this one
df2 <- data.frame(
  FAMID2 = c(1,1,2,2,3,4,5,5,6),
  IID2 = c("A","B","A","B","A","B","A","B","B"),
  Value2 = c(3,6,3,5,6,7,0,4,4),
  DiffValue = c(-3, 3,-2,2,NA, NA, -4, 4, NA),
  Mean = c(4.5,4.5,4,4,NA,NA,2,2,NA))
#   FAMID2 IID2 Value2 DiffValue Mean
# 1      1    A      3        -3  4.5
# 2      1    B      6         3  4.5
# 3      2    A      3        -2  4.0
# 4      2    B      5         2  4.0
# 5      3    A      6        NA   NA
# 6      4    B      7        NA   NA
# 7      5    A      0        -4  2.0
# 8      5    B      4         4  2.0
# 9      6    B      4        NA   NA

Is there any way to do it in a long format?
Thank you so much in advance.

What is the logic behind DiffValue and Mean?

I am working with twins and it is a type of analysis. Instead of compare individuals, difference scores are compared so genetic factors (and other confounders are controlled)

as.data.frame(cbind(...)) is a wrong way to create a data.frame. It makes all columns converted into the same type. Check str(df) to see that Value is character type, not numeric. You should use df <- data.frame(FAMID, IID, Value) instead.

Then you do not need to reshape your data. It is a simple grouping task. There are hundreds of resources on SO for both base and dplyr. And some for reshape2.

You may try this :
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(DiffValue = if (n() == 1) NA else {
    a = Value[1] - Value[2]
    c(a, -a)
    },
    Mean = if (n() == 1) NA else mean(Value), .by = FAMID)

#  FAMID IID Value DiffValue Mean
#1     1   A     3        -3  4.5
#2     1   B     6         3  4.5
#3     2   A     3        -2  4.0
#4     2   B     5         2  4.0
#5     3   A     6        NA   NA
#6     4   B     7        NA   NA
#7     5   A     0        -4  2.0
#8     5   B     4         4  2.0
#9     6   B     4        NA   NA



Thanks for your response  @Ronak Shah  but I get this error:  Error in mutate():
ℹ In argument: DiffValue = if (n() == 1) NA else c(Value[1] - Value[2], Value[2] - Value[1]).
ℹ In group 1: FAMID = "1".
Caused by error in Value[1] - Value[2]:

@JuanJMV Yes, that is because you have incorrectly created the sample dataframe using as.data.frame(cbind(...)). Run the code on data from your edited post and use df from it.

Using by from base:
by(df, ~FAMID, \(x) { if(nrow(x)==1L) { x$Diff=NA; x$Mean=NA } else { 
  d=x$Value[1L]-x$Value[2L]; x$Diff=c(d, -d); x$Mean=mean(x$Value) }; x[-1L]}) |> 
  array2DF()

    FAMID IID Value Diff Mean
1       1   A     3   -3  4.5
1.1     1   B     6    3  4.5
2       2   A     3   -2  4.0
2.1     2   B     5    2  4.0
3       3   A     6   NA   NA
4       4   B     7   NA   NA
5       5   A     0   -4  2.0
5.1     5   B     4    4  2.0
6       6   B     4   NA   NA

